# Signalr unable to update view when message is pushed from controller

Tags: c#, signalr

I am new to SignalR and learning the basics. I am trying send a push message to client from my controller action.

In controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
     GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessageHub>().Clients.All.send("Some msg");
        return View();
    }
```

In javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var messageHub = $.connection.messageHub;

    $.connection.hub.start();
   messageHub.client.send = function (content) {
        alert(content);
        $("#div1").text('abc');
        alert('done');
    }
```

Since, the server calls the client method before loading the view, I am only able to see alert messages from JS and unable to update the view. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: For simple tesing start timer and if timer ends then send your message. Maybe you should draw what you like to do before you start programming

Answer (score 0):

For that simple test I would create a simple timer like

```
public class Clock
{
    private static Clock _instance;
    private Timer timer;
    private Clock()
    {
        timer = new Timer(200);
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ClockHub>().Clients.All.sendTime(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
    }

    public static Clock Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new Clock();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Create instance of this timer at startup of your application